# Enum class with multiple object values

Tags: java, enums

I am not too familiar with enum classes in java. And was wondering if this is an appropriate way to do the following.. (or if there is a better way of doing this)

Essentially what I am trying to do is I have a list of Employees and I'd like to associate with it specific subclasses of parent classes.

```
public enum Employees {
    BOB (new Level2Salary(salaryPlan), new SystemsDept()) 
    MARY (new Level3Salary(salaryPlan), new SoftwareDept()),
    SUSAN (new Level2Salary(salaryPlan), new SystemsDept()),
    PETER (new BaseSalary(salaryPlan), new TestDept());

    private Salary salary;
    private Dept dept;

    Employees(Salary salary, Dept dept){
        this.salary = salary;
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public Salary getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public Salary getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
}

public class Level2Salary extends Salary {

    private SalaryPlan salaryPlan;

    public Level2Salary(SalaryPlan salaryPlan) {
        this.salaryPLan = salaryPlan;
    }
}

public class SystemsDept extends Dept {
    public SystemsDept(){}
}
```

}

I want to be able to do this so when I call `Employees.BOB.getSalary()` it will return the appropriate instantiated subclass that is associated with this enum value. (i.e. `Level2Salary` subclass)

If anyone has better suggestions of this besides using enums, feel free to suggest. Thanks

Comment: enums are meant more for states or flags, like RED, GREEN, BLUE. If you want a _List_ of employees, see e.g. [List<E> interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and implementations. With polymorphism and subclassing, you can do `List<Employee>` where Employee is class with members SalaryPlan and Dept. If you'd like I'll write a more detailed answer when i get time

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done with an enum.  However, you can make a non-enum class which acts just like an enum:  Create a class which only has private constructors, but which has public static final fields whose types are the class itself.  Many classes introduced before Java 5 are examples of this, such as:

- [TextAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html)
- [DateFormat.Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.Field.html)
- [JobState](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/JobState.html)
- [FileChannel.MapMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.MapMode.html)

The newer [StandardSocketOptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html) not only follows the above pattern, but also uses generics to do exactly what you want:  It allows the [NetworkChannel.getOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/NetworkChannel.html#getOption-java.net.SocketOption-) method to return a different subtype for each constant.

In your case, you would replace your enum type with a class designed like StandardSocketOptions:

```
public class Employees<S extends Salary, D extends Dept> {

    public static final Employees<Level2Salary, SystemsDept> BOB =
        new Employees<>(new Level2Salary(salaryPlan), new SystemsDept());

    public static final Employees<Level3Salary, SoftwareDept> MARY =
        new Employees<>(new Level3Salary(salaryPlan), new SoftwareDept());

    public static final Employees<Level2Salary, SystemsDept> SUSAN =
        new Employees<>(new Level2Salary(salaryPlan), new SystemsDept());

    public static final Employees<BaseSalary, TestDept> PETER =
        new Employees<>(new BaseSalary(salaryPlan), new TestDept());

    private final S salary;
    private final D dept;

    private Employees(S salary, D dept){
        this.salary = salary;
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public S getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public D getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution..but how do I tell the subclass what "salaryPlan" is when instantiating?

Comment: You'd need some kind of builder method, which obviously prevents you fro hardcoding the employees in as final fields.